# Set value and Get the values of all the items in the listview Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` which is :

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="166dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

And there is `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cont"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />
```

How I am adding data in my listview.

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {


                }
            });
```

I am trying to update the listview value :

```
View v=listView.getChildAt(position);
                    TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    tv.setText(firstNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().toString()+" "+lastNameDialog.getText().toString().trim().toString());
```

But this is not changing the value

I want that when the image view is clicked then I can get the values of the listview item to get stored in the form of array. How could i get all the items values of a listview and how could set the values again on the clicked item

Comment: simply use ImageView onClick and you have already ListView data in **list**.

Comment: actually after the listview is getting set by adapter values .then i am setting up new data on click on each item.Or i can say that i am changing the data of the items on click

Comment: on click of the item i am opening a custom dialog .in that there is a edit text in that the user is entering a name.them i am setting that name on the  item clicked by the user from the listview

Comment: May be you store your data anywhere after changing. so use that..

Answer (score 1):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
                String[] listData = new String[count];
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    listData[i] = listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: how about setting the item values i have the position

Comment: @User not getting you...now what an issue?

Comment: i am asking if i have the postion of the item .den how could i settext on that item of the listview

Comment: you are using **list** for display data so change in list like as list[posistion]="your value" and set **adapater.notifyDataSetChanged()**

Comment: if i am doing this it is showin this error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ListView"

Answer (score 0):

The process is quite simple, what you can do is, on clicking the image view, iterate through the array adapter which you are using to populate the listview. while iterating you can declare an array and keep inserting the iterated values inside it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
int wantedPosition = position; // Whatever position you're looking for
int firstPosition = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition() -mList.getHeaderViewsCount();

int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;
if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= mList.getChildCount()) {
    return;
}

Button btnEdit = (Button)wantedView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
btnEdit.setText("my new message");
```

Have you tried something like this

Answer (score 0):

Use the `adapter`. In cycle get the values from adapter :

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i>adapter.getCount();i++)
    b.append(adapter.getItem(i));//May be toString() should be used.
```

Comment: This should be `i < adapter.getCount();`. As it currently stands, this is an infinite loop.

Comment: It's not an infinite loop - it will simply never reach the `append` statement because the `i` integer (starting at 0) will never be greater than `adapter.getCount()` unless the adapter somehow had a count of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

for changing values of a list item you should do it in the adapter class.
so if your item has a `TextView`you should write a method in adapter like this

```
public void changeText(String newValue) {
this.myTextView.setText(newValue);
}
```

this is also the case when using view holder.
for getting all the items values, basically you should do what first answer said.

> imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>      public void onClick(View v) {
>                   int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
>                   String[] listData = new String[count];
>                   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
>                       listData[i] = listView.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString();
>                   }
>               }
>           });
>   but except `getCount` you could use `size()`.
>   but at least for me these relations between adapter and list is a little confusing.
>   hope it helps.