# Edit text showing red underLine on the Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am using a `EditText` to take date from the user. So when I am running my application on the default value that I have given it is underlining the text in red.
**XML Code**

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/setDate"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:text="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

And in my **Activity**

```
date.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

Why does it underline the text in red? Once the date is set then it is not showing me the red underline.

Comment: Does it underline the text in you `EditText` field? Do any errors occur? Does you Logcat show anything related to this?

Comment: yes it underline the text in the EditText that is dd/mm/yyyy.No there in no error nothing in there it just red uderline on the text in UI

Comment: @AndroidRookie u have any idea about listview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308228/set-value-and-get-the-values-of-all-the-items-in-the-listview-android/18308493?noredirect=1#18308493

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to disable spellcheck Android edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449505/how-to-disable-spellcheck-android-edittext)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I assume, that this is your spell check, so add:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: For some reason this here fixed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007388/android-view-windowmanagerbadtokenexception-list-view-set-text-then-focus god knows why...

Comment: After applying your suggestion the whole text started to appear in one line (no word wrap). There must be some side-effect. Besides that it is not clear what this red underlining mean (it began in Nougat) as the correct words are underlined too.

Comment: @ka3ak Maybe you introduced a Typo/linebreak, etc. when entering this Code? And have you checked if it checks against the correct lamguage (e.g. english & not your local one? ) I can't help you with this issue, but assure that there are no side effects to disabeling the Suggestions.

Comment: @printxdiv0 If EditText contains multiple lines your solution would put the whole text in one line. I had to use android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" to keep multi-line text. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33993169/971355

Comment: ka3ak. Please use                     
 android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" for multiple lines.

Comment: Succinct. Thanks