# how to disable spellcheck Android edittext

Tags: android

I want to remove the underlines from texts inside edittext fields. [image: text fileds with underlined texts inside]

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show related codes? Did you add the codes, or is it a spell check thing?

Comment: make you tried by disabling Spell Check `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` ?

Comment: how i show the redline in my edittext can you please tell me?

Comment: @SNandhini Use this:

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType=
        "textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
    ... />

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Sandah Aung.But its not working for me.

Comment: @SHemaNandhini did you figure out how to show the red line under misspelled words? I can't get it to work either

Comment: @ Bassel Mourjan i was using the sandah Anug gave some code for showing the red line.i told that was not working.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

You can do it with following code. Just paste it in layout of `EditText`.

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: I found that this will remove all line breaks when this is set.

Comment: i used floating editText and faced this problem but your solution not work with me and when focus on editText the app crashed with     java.io.IOException: null InputStream

Comment: @AmalKronz This solution is for `EditText` only. Not tested with floating EditText. (I guess you mean by `TextInputlayout`)

Comment: ya,i mean TextInputLayout ,when the error appear and try to edit it the app crashed ,can you help me ,please?

Comment: Careful, this disables keyboard suggestions too.

Comment: Works great for AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView

Answer (score 75):

In order to get rid of spell checking you have to specify the `EditText`'s InputType in the XML as the following:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

However, if your `EditText` is multiline and also you need to get rid of spell checking,then you have to specify the EditText's InputType in the XML as the following:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 25):

Minor addition to Chintan's answer - such (and other) combination is also allowed:
`android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"`

Answer (score 14):

Or if you want to just disable the red underline (and the autocorrect dialog), you can override the `isSuggestionsEnabled()` method on `TextView`.

This will keep the keyboard autocomplete working.

Comment: Could you please provide your suggested implementation of isSuggestionsEnabled()?

Comment: `return false;`

Comment: A perfect solution for apps such as "Notes" - you can write any custom words you like without mistakes being red underlined, but still, you got all suggestions to text faster.

Answer (score 7):

I just Added a line in for EditText
`editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);`

and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

So I was not able to find out any direct way of doing it. So went ahead with below workaround:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

As the input type becomes a visible password, even if the spell check is enabled from the device settings, the Red underline won't appear. :)

Comment: +1 ^this, I had a problem that when typing space (" ") then comma (".") the EditText's text would change into ". " and not " ." as I intended, adding "textVisiblePassword" as you suggested solved it for me, thank you :)