# In an EditText, is there a way to disable the autocorrect on a span?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

I've got an `EditText` that can have custom spans and I don't want them to be part of the spell check. I know I could use the flag `android:inputType=textNoSuggestions` to completely disable the suggestions but I would like to handle it based on the position of the cursor and if it's focusing my span or not.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check (using position of the cursor is focusing your span or not) whether or not suggestions should be shown, and try to change inputType dynamically: editText.setInputType(InputType.XXXX); If I correctly caught what you'd like to do...

Comment: Well, that would be a way to solve it but the problem is that it would toggle the complete/correct on the whole text, which could feel a bit weird. Ideally I would like a NoAutocorrectSpan. Maybe I can build it...

Comment: Hi Romain! I know it's been awhile, but maybe you've solved this? If so, please share it

Answer (score 0):

1) There is a good trick for it. Please take a look at the simekadam's answer. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36479831/9169701

As described in the post all you have to do is override `isSuggestionsEnabled()` method in `TextView` like this:

```
override fun isSuggestionsEnabled(): Boolean {
    return false
}
```

2) You also can use this solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34657536/9169701