# Redrawing EditText after changing InputType

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have made a class that is responsible for monitoring an `EditText` widget following the Observer pattern. Its sole function is to disable or re-enable auto-correct based on a method call. I am able to successfully achieve this, but the problem is that the new `InputType` only applies to new text I add to the `EditText` - old text still retains the red underline to show that it can be auto-corrected.

Is there any way I can force the new `InputType` to apply to the entire `EditText` block, and not simply the new content I add? I tried calling `editText.invalidate()` and `editText.refreshDrawableState()` in the hope all the text would refresh, but to no avail.

```
final class SpellCheckerObserver implements EditTextObserver {

    public static final int KEY = KeyGenerator.generateUniqueId();

    private int defaultInputType;

    SpellCheckerObserver(EditTextSubject subject) {
        subject.attach(SpellCheckerObserver.KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void activating(EditText editText) {

        defaultInputType = editText.getInputType();   
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);

    }

    @Override
    public void deactivating(EditText editText) {
        editText.setInputType(defaultInputType);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer whilst looking through the source code for `TextView`, where I came across the [`removeSuggestionSpans()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.removeSuggestionSpans%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.I wasn't aware that the suggestions were in fact a type of span, (unsurprisingly, the [`SuggestionSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SuggestionSpan.html))

This meant I was able to remove the red underline with the following code:

```
SuggestionSpan[] spans = editText.getText().getSpans(
        0, editText.length(), SuggestionSpan.class
);

if (spans.length > 0) {
    for (SuggestionSpan span : spans) {
        editText.getText().removeSpan(span);
    }
}
```