# EditText. Red cursor and underline

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

When creating an EditText for a form, The cursor and underline appears in red.

[image: phone gif]

How solve this?

After finding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449505/how-to-disable-spellcheck-android-edittext) solution I added:

```
android:inputType="phone|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: do you want remove that cusror

Comment: @NileshRathod I want it appears in white.

Comment: put <color name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</color> to your colors.xml file

Comment: Create a style that redefine "android:colorAccent" to white, and set it to your EditText or entire Activity or even your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your theme's accent color to white, to change the color of this line and cursor. Your accent color is set to red right now.

To do this, go to styles.xml and check what your main App theme's "colorAccent" is pointing to. Probably it is pointing to '@color/accent' like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" ... >
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    ...
```

To then update the accent color of your app, change your 'accent' (or whatever id it has for you in the styles.xml) in colors.xml to white, like this:

```
<color name="accent">@android:color/white</color>
```

Comment: if you can, please show an example of _how_ to change that accent color.