# Disabling red underlines / spell checking when TextView is not focused

Tags: android, textview

I have TextViews configured like this:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine|textImeMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"
```

On Android 6.0 / Nexus 5, everything works correctly when entering text (auto-correction, suggestions as you type, etc...), but when done editing and the TextView is not in focus anymore, any misspelled words has ugly red underlines. How do you get rid of them?

I have read questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332694/edit-text-showing-red-underline-on-the-text/18333842) on Stack Overflow but the suggestion of adding `textNoSuggestions` is not acceptable since it removes the red underlines but also breaks autocorrection as you type while the Text View is focused.

I also tried using a focus change listener on the TextView but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    setOnFocusChangeListener(new TextView.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);
            } else {
                setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
            }
        }

    });
```

**[UPDATE 1]** I realized that my subclass of `EditText` which calls `setOnFocusChangeListener()` in the constructor (I verified this works), does not trigger a call to `onFocusChange()` whenever the user starts or ends editing text in the text view (which means when the keyboard is displayed or hidden).

**[UPDATE 2]** I figured why `onFocusChange()` wasn't called: turns out there was another place in the app where `setOnFocusChangeListener()` was called on the same TextView, overriding it. It works now, but calling `setInputType()` to unset `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` while not in focus has no effect: red lines remain visible. To be precise, setting or not setting `textNoSuggestions` in XML has an effect, but attempt to override it programmatically from within `onFocusChange()` has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is working correct only you need to add below line
call `setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)` in your Activity

> Sample Code

```
tv.setOnFocusChangeListener(new TextView.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                tv.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT);
            } else {
                tv.setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE | EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion but still can't get it to work: see the update in my question.

Comment: @Pol use instead of EditorInfo use InputType

Comment: `EditorInfo` implements `InputType` so the values are the same, I tried, no difference.